# Jsoup html parsing unselect elements with multiple classes

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

How to prevent jsoup from selecting elements having multiple classes. Like i want to select element having class1 but not elements having both class1 and class2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions:

1) This only works if the elements you want to select really only carry exactly one class and if there are no random spaces in front of or after the class attribute:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("[class=class1]")
```

2) You can use pseudo-selectors:

```
Elements elements = doc.select(".class1:not(.class2)")
```

See https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax for more info on this.